# How to make dynamic API calls depending on user preferences?

Tags: java, android

I am using theMovieDb.com API to fetch data.On launching the app it shows grid view of popular movies. In setting menu, it has option to sort the grid view on the basis of more popular and highest rated. I am using shared preferences to store user preferences and a listener on preference change.But unable to sort the grid view.

MainActivityFragment.java

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view_movies);
    final ImageAdapter mAdapter= new ImageAdapter(getActivity(),listMovie);
    gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            Movie movieSelected= listMovie.get(position);
            String movieTitle=movieSelected.getTitle();
            String movieThumbnail=movieSelected.getUrlThumbnail();
            String movieReleaseDate=movieSelected.getReleaseDate();
            String movieOverview=movieSelected.getOverview();
            String movieRating = movieSelected.getRating();
            Intent i = new Intent( getActivity() ,DetailsMovies.class);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_1, movieThumbnail);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_2, movieTitle);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_3, movieReleaseDate);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_4, movieRating);
            i.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE_5, movieOverview);

            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    return rootView;
}


private void sendJsonRequest() {
    //In the case of theMovieDB it is JSON Object Request
    //Specify several argument in JSON Object Request
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            getRequestUrl(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    parseJsonResponse(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            });
    requestQueue.add(request);

}

private void parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
    if (response == null || response.length() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    long id = -1;
    String title = Constants.NA;
    String releaseDate = Constants.NA;
    String synopsis = Constants.NA;
    String urlThumbnail = Constants.NA;
    String rating = Constants.NA;

    try {
        if (response.has(KEY_RESULTS)) {
            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray(KEY_RESULTS);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject currentMovies = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                //Get the id of the current movie
                //If statement is used to check whether id is null or not.
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_ID) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_ID)) {
                    id = currentMovies.getLong(KEY_ID);
                }
                //Get the synopsis of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_OVERVIEW) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_OVERVIEW)) {
                    synopsis = currentMovies.getString(KEY_OVERVIEW);
                }
                //Get the title of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_TITLE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_TITLE)) {
                    title = currentMovies.getString(KEY_TITLE);
                }
                //Get the urlThumbnail of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_POSTER_PATH) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_POSTER_PATH)) {
                    urlThumbnail = currentMovies.getString(KEY_POSTER_PATH);
                }
                //Get the release date of the current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_RELEASE_DATE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_RELEASE_DATE)) {
                    releaseDate = currentMovies.getString(KEY_RELEASE_DATE);
                }
                //Get the rating of current movie
                if (currentMovies.has(KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE) && !currentMovies.isNull(KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE)) {
                    rating = currentMovies.getString(KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE);
                }
                //Create movie object
                movie=new Movie();
                movie.setId(id);
                movie.setTitle(title);
                movie.setUrlThumbnail("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + urlThumbnail);
                movie.setReleaseDate(releaseDate);
                movie.setOverview(synopsis);
                movie.setRating(rating);
                //This decides when to add movies to the ArrayList
                if (id != -1 && !title.equals(Constants.NA)) {
                    listMovie.add(movie);
                }

            }

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());

    }

}

public String getRequestUrl() {
    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    String order = pref.getString(getString(R.string.pref_order_key), getString(R.string.pref_popularity));

    if(order.equals(getString(R.string.pref_rating)))
        return URL + "vote_average" + UrlEndpoints.URL_PARAM + MyApplication.API_KEY;
    else
        return  URL+ "popularity"+UrlEndpoints.URL_PARAM + MyApplication.API_KEY;

}


//Base Adapter which is used to put poster in grid view
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Movie> movieItems;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Movie> movieList) {
        this.mContext = c;
        this.movieItems = movieList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return movieItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return movieItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        }
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_movies, null);
        }

            mNetworkImageView = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById
                    (R.id.networkImageView);
            //Getting movie data for the row
            Movie m = movieItems.get(position);
            //Thumbnail Image
            //ImageLoader is used to load the images from json object retrieved.
            imageLoader=VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();
            mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(m.getUrlThumbnail(), imageLoader);
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

}

SettingsActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add 'general' preferences, defined in the XML file
    // Added preferences from XML
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);


    // For all preferences, attach an OnPreferenceChangeListener so the UI summary can be
    // updated when the preference changes.
    // Added preferences
    bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_order_key)));
}

/**
 * Attaches a listener so the summary is always updated with the preference value.
 * Also fires the listener once, to initialize the summary (so it shows up before the value
 * is changed.)
 */
private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
    // Set the listener to watch for value changes.
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    // Trigger the listener immediately with the preference's
    // current value.
    onPreferenceChange(preference,
            PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext())
                    .getString(preference.getKey(), ""));
}

@Override
public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object value) {
    String stringValue = value.toString();

    if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
        // For list preferences, look up the correct display value in
        // the preference's 'entries' list (since they have separate labels/values).
        ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) preference;
        int prefIndex = listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
        if (prefIndex >= 0) {
            preference.setSummary(listPreference.getEntries()[prefIndex]);
        }
    } else {
        // For other preferences, set the summary to the value's simple string representation.
        preference.setSummary(stringValue);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So you need to store the sort option, right?

Comment: I want to sort the grid view depending on the user preferences. Can I make different API calls ? as i have done in getRequestUrl() method of main activity.